# SlidingMenu slide but not move the back view

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu

I am using this sliding menu : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu in my application.

What i would like to update about this component is that the front view to slide over the back view, and thus the back view should stay in the initial position, just the above view to slide over it. Are there some properties about this i could work with?

These are the current properties i have set to my SlidingMenu:

```
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    // sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
```

Thanks!

**SEE THE LINKS IN THE ANSWERS BELOW FOR SOLUTION!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using navigation drawer provided in support V4

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the sliding menu example from here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

The code is much cleaner than what i was using and it doesn't lag at all on older devices, highly recommended!